# $(window).resize not firing function properly on height/width condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a fixed-positioned full-screen image gallery. The container div height is set via jQuery, and the next div (#page) has a margin-top equal to window.height.

Here is this code:

```
var windowH = $(window).height();
var windowW = $(window).width();

function marginTop() {
    var currentH = $(window).height();
    $("#page").css("margin-top", currentH +'px');
    $("#image-gallery").css("height", currentH +'px');
    console.log('mTop fired!');
};

$(window).resize(function() {
        var newH = $(window).height();     // Records new windows height after resize
        var newW = $(window).width();
        var maxH = windowH + 90;        // Sets a positive delta of some px
        var maxW = windowW + 60;
        var minH = windowH - 90;      // Sets a negative delta of some px
        var minW = windowW - 60;
            if(newH > maxH) {           // If the height difference is more than 50px, then set new marginTop for #page
                marginTop();
                console.log('fire for bigger height');
            } else if(newH < minH) {
                marginTop();
                console.log('fire for smaller height');
            } else if(newW > maxW) {
                marginTop();
                console.log('fire for bigger width');
            } else if(newW < minW ) {
                marginTop();
                console.log('fire for smaller width');
            }
});
```

I've split the conditions in several `else if` statement because it didn't work fine, and I had to check out when it was working, when not.

The various if...elseif...elseif... solve a problem on mobile browsers: without that delta, the #image-gallery div would change dimension when the address bar appears or disappears, resulting in stuttering adjustments of the div's height. Moreover, i did not want to redraw the whole thing for small changes in viewport on desktop too.

However it has some problem, as it doesn't work correctly. In particular:

- marginTop() is fired only for window.resize with smaller height (checked from console.log)
- on desktop, if the window is resized through the top-right-corner button, it doesn't fire at all.
- removing all the if-else-if conditions, it works fine on desktop in any situation (but the address-bar is still a problem on mobile)

Can't figure it out, the code seems fine to me, but not to browsers. Where's the catch?

Tested on Firefox and Chrome latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a host of small problems here. Your if statement, as is, will never reach the width compares. First of all, with the width being in a `if else` with the height, then height is always evaluated first and width is never hit if height is adjusted.

Next, your "current height|width" as seen at `var windowH = $(window).height();` is never reset. This means, if the user show up with a viewport (say browser is minimized) of 200:150, then height:width will always be measured based on 200:150. This would make for a very different experience from someone using a much larger viewport.

Another issue, often found with window re-sizing, is the multiple amount of times your code will fire. This can cause major issue with overlapping commands, thus causing double feedback.

Below is how I would handle this and a suggested rebuild.

```js
/* simple method to get the current window size as an object where h=height && w=width */
function getWindowSize() {
 return { h: $(window).height(), w: $(window).width() };
}

function doWork(typ, msg) {
 // report msg of change to console
 console.log(typ == 'h' ? 'HEIGHT:\t' : 'WIDTH:\t', msg);
 
 // we really only need fire your method if height has changed
 if (typ == 'h') marginTop();
 
 // a change was made, now to reset 
 window.sizeCheck = getWindowSize();
}

// your original method
// brokered off so it can be used independently 
function marginTop() {
 var currentH = $(window).height();
 console.log('currentH', currentH)
 $("#page").css("margin-top", currentH +'px');
 $("#image-gallery, #page").height(currentH);
 console.log('mTop fired!');
}

/* action area for window resize event */
function windowResize() {
 // made my variables short and sweet,
 // sch=sizeCheck, scu=sizeCurrent
 var sch = window.sizeCheck, // get previously set size
  scu = getWindowSize(),
  maxH = sch.h + 90,
  minH = sch.h - 90,
  maxW = sch.w + 60,
  minW = sch.w - 60;
 
 if (scu.h > maxH) doWork('h', 'View Got <b>Taller</b>');
 else if (scu.h < minH) doWork('h', 'View Got <i>shorteR</i>');
 
 // for what you want, the following isn't even really nec
 // but i'll leave it in so you can see the work
 if (scu.w > maxW) doWork('w', 'View Got <b>Wider</b>');
 else if (scu.w < minW) doWork('w', 'View Got <i>thinneR</i>');
}

$(function() {
 // ezier to maintain one global variable than to scope 
 // shot 2 which could easily be overriden in a latter method, 
 // by simple confusion
 window.sizeCheck = getWindowSize();
 
 // call of event to establish correct margin for the page div
 marginTop()
 
 $(window).resize(function(e) {
  // this will clear our timer everytime resize is called
  if (this.tmrResize) clearTimeout(this.tmrResize);
  // resize is called multiple times per second, 
  // this helps to seperate the call,
  // and ensure a little time gap (1/4 second here)
  this.tmrResize = setTimeout(windowResize, 250);
 });
})
```

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#image-gallery {
 background: blue;
 color: white;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
#page { background: white; color: red; height: 400px; position: relative; z-index: 1; }
p { padding: 3em; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image-gallery">
 <p>
  image Gallery
 </p>
</div>
<div id="page">
 <p>
  next page
 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @SpYk3HH for the commented explanation, I've learned PHP while building WordPress templates and I'm new to jQuery / Js logic so I still need some practice, as I've never attended a course! Tomorrow I'll try your suggestion, hope it will work now!

Answer (score 1):

Someone passed by and then voted -1 to my question. I'd just like to know who's the braveheart that judges others without even posting a simple comment. This behaviour should be forbidden, we're not on 9gag neither 4chan.

Comment: 110% completely agreed. FYI, i'll be looking at your problem after my smoke break ... prepare to be fixed.